# Windows message vs Events

Tags: windows, winapi, events, message

I am new to MFC and the concept of Windows messaging. What are the differences or similarities between windows messages and events? say when a user presses a key or the close button of a control, is it going to be a message or event?

Thanks

Comment: The winapi is specified in the C programming language.  C doesn't have any notion of events.  So the winapi uses messages to implement something similar.  Which then often get translated into something event-like by a class library.  A method call in MFC when you use its message mapping macros.  Avoid trying MFC without reading a book about it first, you won't get far without one.

Comment: The word "event" is heavily overloaded in Windows. Please be more specific what type of event you are referring to. Without context, people usually mean "kernel event" as created by `CreateEvent`, but perhaps you're referring to something else.

Comment: The same concept that is in .Net (event)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the user presses a key, or performs any other form of input, the system places messages in the message queue. Then, your app must pull off those messages in its message loop, and deal with them.

Many UI frameworks will process those messages for you and convert them into events. Note that the events that you talk about are not events in any sense that Windows defines. That use of events refers to a concept defined in whatever programming language/framework you are using. [Windows events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915.aspx) are used for thread synchronization.

The top level message loop may look like this:

```
MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

The call to `DispatchMessage` results in a window procedure being called. The GUI framework typically implements that window procedure and converts the message into an event.

So, the executive summary is that:

1. Input events lead to messages.
2. The GUI framework converts the messages into events.
3. You implement event handlers to respond to those events.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what do you mean by "The GUI framework converts the messages into events"? I thought all messages will be dispatched  to their own handlers based on the message map. So where dose this conversion fit in?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain, with a link to some reference, precisely what you mean by the term event. That way we can be sure we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: The following URL "Message Handling and Mapping" explains these issues really good: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6d1asasd(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I have come from .Net (C#) background, therefore I naturally know events in that concept. events and event handlers, like for buttons in a form or other custom events defined by this 'event' keyword.

Comment: The thing is I have seen windows message in MFC like WM_CLOSE for a Dialog and then you also can define an event handler for the close button, so dose that mean when the user presses the close button there would a windows message and a separate event?

Comment: MFC message maps convert those Windows messages into member function calls which I guess is what you mean by events. So messages lead to member function calls. MFC doesn't call them events but they are pretty much the same as .net events. Even in .net there are both messages and events. And it's done in just the same way as I describe in the answer.